# Finding a test statistic when you don't know the distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-power, joint-distribution, asymptotics

I am working on this problem from my class and it has stumped me for a while now. I will show a picture of the problem and then my work/thoughts:

[image]

Now we are not given the individual distribution of $X_1$ or $X_2$ which makes it difficult to move forward for me. All of the examples in the text focused on Normal RV. I *think* we may need to use the central limit theorem and say that whatever test statistic we come up with, will diverge in distribution to the standard normal distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

This problem is not for marks in my course but it is recommended for the upcoming midterm. I'd greatly appreciate detailed help.

Many thanks!

Comment: This is indeed an asymptotic test that relies on convergence theorems like the CLT, which allows you to have asymptotic type I error and power. You could start by looking at the asymptotic behaviour of $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \{X_{1i}-X_{2i}\}$$

Comment: It might also help to realize that the phrasing of "a test statistic" was well chosen, because there is no unique answer: there are infinitely many test statistics that will satisfy criteria (i) and (ii).